# How can I have a script set the time during boot on Intel Mac OSX

Tags: macos, mac, boot, time

My computer's battery is bad, but I don't really want to spend the money to replace it because it still lasts several hours. But when it gets down to about 10%, it sometimes just completely powers down the computer without warning. When this happens the internal clock is reset to December 31, 2000. I don't think the clock is maintained by a watch battery like in PC's, otherwise I'd just change that.

Anyhow, once the OS loads, I get a warning that the date is set to before 2008 and that some applications may fail to function properly, my WiFi being one of them. I then need to perform a few steps to change the time, save it, log off and log back on. It's just a minor pain in the butt, but I'd like to have a script similar to a PC's autoexec.bat file do the work for me.

During boot up I'd like to have a script check the time. If it's before 2008, then set it to a date beyond 2008. As long as the date is after January 1, 2008 then my WiFi will work and the system will automatically correct the time in a few moments.

I'm running OSX 10.6.8 on an Intel based Mac.

Thanks in advance for your help,
Pete

Comment: I'll let you make the script since you haven't told us what you've tried, but for what you need to run on boot - `crontab` would probably be the easiest.  In a terminal type `crontab -e` and for the command, you'll want `@reboot /path/to/my/script`.  Note: Since on some *nix environments, time is a sudo right - you may need to do that from a root terminal.

Comment: I haven't tried anything. Unlike Windows based PCs, I know absolutely nothing about Macs and I couldn't really find much help googling it. I don't know what file to edit nor do I know the the syntax for the script, but that I could probably figure out. That crontab command, will it make my file run on every reboot or just the next reboot. I want to run this check every time. 

Root terminal???

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Scheduling**

To run a command on a schedule, your best bet is probably using `crontab`

> Cron is a time-based job scheduler in Unix-like computer operating
>   systems. The name cron comes from the word "chronos", Greek for
>   "time". Cron enables users to schedule jobs (commands or shell
>   scripts) to run periodically at certain times or dates.

So, you can set up scripts and/or programs, etc. to execute on a schedule with this.  For your uses, the most applicable *timer* is `@reboot` which will run on each reboot.  The actual syntax for this would be as follows:

```
@reboot /path/to/my/script
```

Since on some unixy systems, date controlling stuff is root - you may need to edit `crontab` from a root terminal - so do this (you need to have admin/sudo rights):

1. Open a Terminal
2. type `sudo -i` or `su -`
3. Type `crontab -e` (that opens crontab in your environmental text editor
4. Put the above *on its own line* (`@reboot /path/to/my/script`)
5. Exit and Save (the actual commands depend on which editor you use)
6. Make sure that the script is marked executable (`chmod +x /path/to/my/script`)

**The Actual Script**

So, like I said above - I'd like to see you do some of the footwork on that since *we aren't a script writing service*, but I may as well give you a start.

You can use the `date` command with parameters to get the current system time - you could do that with `date '+%Y'`

So here is a comparison based on year:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sysYr=$(date '+%Y')
cutoff=2008

if [[ $sysYr -lt $cutoff ]]; then
    echo "It's before ${cutoff}!"
else
   echo "It's ${cutoff} or greater!"
fi
```

Breakdown of the above:

1. This just tells the system where to look for the program that runs the script, this is more portable than `/usr/bin/bash` as used to be common.  I believe it also works on mac.  If not, type `which bash` and you can point directly to it instead.
2. The `$( something )` is [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) which replaces the command with the output of the command.  In this case, we are running `date '+%Y'` which will expand out (currently) to the integer 2013
3. Setting another variable for the cutoff, just for *good code* sake.
4. Compare and do conditional commands.  Generally, it is best to quote items being compared to protect against spaces and such; however, these are numerals and there is no reason they shouldn't be, also `-lt` is the bash comparison for a numeral "less than".
5. The rest is fairly self explanatory - `echo` displays the following text.

Comment: Hey nerdwaller, thanks so much for your help. Your answer was clear and concise, and most importantly it WORKS!!! :) I learned so much about Apple Scripting during the past few days, but it's becoming habitual.